# Reference non-initiated variable at top of file

Tags: swift, variable-declaration

this is a bit odd to say but essentially here is my code below:

```
import UIKit

class BarcodeScanPopover: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var navbar: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var product: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productimage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scanner: UIView!
    var scan: MTBBarcodeScanner = MTBBarcodeScanner(previewView: scanner);
    override func viewDidLoad() {
```

So the issue I'm having is I can't declare "scan" without initiating the `MTBBarcodeScanner` object, but at the same time, I can't initiate the `MTBBarcodeScanner` object without calling "scanner" which is not possible at the top of the file. Unfortunately `MTBBarcodeScanner()` is not a valid init and causes crashes so that is not possible either.

I need to do this because I need to access "scan" at different points in the code - not just in one code method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you will always have an instance of the `MTBBarcodeScanner` after the view loaded, declare it as `MTBBarcodeScanner!`: `var scan: MTBBarcodeScanner!`. That makes it an implicitly unwrapped optional, which is allowed to be `nil` unless you try to access some property/function on it.

You should therefore then make sure that you always assign something to it before ever accessing it in any other way. That can and should be done in `viewDidLoad`:

```
scan = MTBBarcodeScanner(previewView: scanner)
```

Comment: Dang it - I completely forgot about applying optionals here! Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can let your `MTBBarCodeScanner` instance be an optional, and initially set it to `nil`.

```
var scan: MTBBarcodeScanner? = nil
```

Thereafter call your initializer to update its value as soon as `scanner` instance is available to you (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: `scanner` can probably not be used in the `init` since the outlets are assigned a bit after the init.